# $(this) not working with Flickr Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, gallery, flickr

Please see my codepen for this issue here:
http://codepen.io/dsm/pen/ewEJb

This app will display two Flickr galleries. I'm trying to separate the function to be completely independent from the function call. However, the only way I can currently get it to work is to hardcode the lines to include the div id '#flickr'. I tried using $(this) instead but does not seem to cooperate.

Any suggestions?

```
$('#flickr').append('<h2>'+photosetTitle+'</h2>');
$('#flickr').append(theHtml);
```

The above are the lines of code in question and can be seen in the code below.

Note: this code assumes jquery is already loaded.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.flickrSetGallery = function(callerSettings) { 
        var settings = $.extend(callerSettings); 
        var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=';
        url += settings.apiKey;
        url += '&photoset_id=';
        url += settings.photosetID;
        url += '&format=json&jsoncallback=?';   
        $.getJSON(url, displayImages);
        function displayImages(data) {
            var photosetTitle = data.photoset.title;
            var photosetTag = photosetTitle.toLowerCase().trim().split(/\s+/).join
            var theHtml = "";
            $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,photo){
                var source = 'http://farm'+photo.farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo.server+'/'+photo.id+'_'+photo.secret+'_s.jpg';
                theHtml+= '<li><a href="http://farm'+photo.farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo.server+'/'+photo.id+'_'+photo.secret+'_b.jpg" data-lightbox="'+photosetTag+'">';
                theHtml+= '<img title="'+photo.title+'" src="'+source+'" alt="'+photo.title+'" />';
                theHtml+= '</a></li>';              
            });
            $('#flickr').append('<h2>'+photosetTitle+'</h2>');
            $('#flickr').append(theHtml);
        };
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#flickr').flickrSetGallery({
        apiKey: '2eabc9d4b3a1b7443b2900a729b8b4a8',
        photosetID: '72157616127960344'        
    });
    $('#flickr2').flickrSetGallery({
        apiKey: '403e03feaf4819a91a02f158a0504075',
        photosetID: '72157637557971086'    
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="flickr" class="flickr-things">
</div>

<div id="flickr2" class="flickr-things">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, using `this` inside the callback doesn't posint to the original element it is jqXhr object, so instead you can just cache it to a variable and use it:

Before tha ajax call:

```
var flickrContainer = this; //this is already a jquery object here
$.getJSON(url, displayImages);

......
```

and inside your callback use it as:

```
  flickrContainer.append('<h2>'+photosetTitle+'</h2>');
  flickrContainer.append(theHtml);
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oifvp)**

There are other ways as well like using `$.proxy` `function.bind` etc to bind the context of the ajax callback to the context of the element.

```
 $.getJSON(url, displayImages.bind(this)); // or $.proxy(displayImages,this)
```

and now `this` inside your function represents the flickerContainer so you can just do:

```
  this.append('<h2>'+photosetTitle+'</h2>');
  this.append(theHtml);
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `$(this)` is not a jQuery object containing the flicker element until you `return the object from the plugin`

```
return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //now $this contains the jQuery object of the element/s bound to the plugin
});
```